# <video> tag adding 3px of whitespace to the right

Tags: html, css, video

I have several videos on my website and wish them to be displayed at a certain size. All is working fine, except that for some bizarre reason 3px is added to the left of each video tag.

I've tested the following with `margin-right` set to 0 and there is still 3px of white-space visible, even though Firebug doesn't register it.

How can I fix this issue? Thanks.

Here is the HTML I am using -

```
<video class="video-preview" controls="">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/Everyone-Bat-Out-of-Hell.mp4"></source>
    Sorry, your browser is old and doesn't support the HTML5 'video' tag. Sucks to be you...
</video>
```

And here is the the CSS -

```
video{
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    cursor: pointer;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
#gallery .video-preview{
    height: 118px;
    margin-right: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    width: 210px;
}
```

Comment: are you sure it's not a space character?

Comment: Yep, I'm sure. For one, it's a video, so no text (the non-HTML5 warning is hidden), and for two, Firebug would be showing it if it were a space. Thanks.

Comment: eh, just to be super-duper sure though: http://jsfiddle.net/TL9Ed/ there's "no text" in this fiddle, but the line break between the two `<img>` tags creates a space. I don't have firebug, but Firefox's built-in inspector does not display the space either. -- edit: http://jsfiddle.net/72LUG/ version without line break

Comment: make sure teh width and height match the actual dimensions of the video. Otherwise, the white background will show up. Or just remove the white background.

Comment: @ralph.m - Thanks, they do all match.

Comment: @guest - Ok, I see what you mean. I'll have a fiddle and see what I can come up with...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `video` element is `inline` by default, white space between tags are rendered with a space between them. Much like if you had `<span>a</span> <span>b</span>` it would be rendered as:a b. Therefore if you have the following:

```
<video>....</video>
<video>....</video>
<video>....</video>
```

There will be a space rendered between each of the video elements. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6j9k/)

The quickest and some what dirty solution, is to put the next open tag next to the closing tag:

```
<video>....</video><video>
....</video><video>
....</video>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6j9k/1/)

There are other options depending on your layout. You could add a negative right margin to the video element. Thoug this is not always consitent accross browsers.

The next option is to make the video elements `block` and float them left.

```
 video 
 {
      display:block;
      float:left;
 }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6j9k/2/)

You may need some further tweaking with this approach depending on your layout.